# Magento2 : hsbc payment gateway extension to be compatible with magento2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, payment-gateway

I have hsbc payment gateway extension which is compatible with Magento 1.9 but any have hsbc payment gateway extension which is compatible with magento-2. how i can convert this module magento 1.9 to 2.

Any have any idea or some reference for the achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The Magento 2 has new implementation of payment gateway for payment integrations.

The official [official dev guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html) describes how you can add new payment integration to checkout step.

Also you can see how implemented new version of [Braintree](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree) payment, which will be available in the Magento 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can refer this link related to HSBC Payment Gateway for Magento 2
https://www.polacin.com/hsbc-payment-gateway.html

Comment: Yes, but extension is paid. I need to convert my M1 extension to M2. 

Great solution if we will buy and use.